# Why don't we transmit at rates higher than the Shannon capacity if we are going to get a nonzero probability of error anyways ?

Tags: it.information-theory, shannon

Shannon capacity $C$ is the upper limit on a rate $R$ defined as the number of information symbols $k$ divided by the number of transmitted symbols $n$, that can be transmitted over a channel such that as $n \rightarrow \infty$, the probability of error goes to zero. If a rate $R > C $ is used, the probability of error is bounded away from zero.

Since $n$ is finite in practical applications, there is some nonzero probability of error.Thus, why would it matter if we transmit at a rate higher than $C$, Shannon's theorem predicts that such a rate will have a nonzero probability of error, but we already have a nonzero probability of error due to the fact that $n$ is finite.In other words, why don't we transmit at rates higher than $C$ if we are going to get a nonzero probability of error anyways ?

Comment: Not all nonzero numbers are equal.

Comment: But how do we know that the probability of error caused by transmitting at rates above C will be intolerable ?

Comment: This sounds like an engineering question, not a theoretical CS one.

Comment: @PeterTaylor it can be tcs

Comment: @user2692162 look at gallager's cut off rate work or shannon's proof itself I think you will get explicit exponents of failure probability with length of code

Comment: This paper talks about the achievable rates for any given error probability at finite blocklenghts. http://people.lids.mit.edu/yp/homepage/data/finite_block.pdf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look at the [strong converse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noisy-channel_coding_theorem#Strong_converse_for_discrete_memoryless_channels) to Shannon's theorem:

> for rates above the channel capacity, if $n$ bits are to be transmitted, the probability of error is exponentially close to 1, so $1-e^{c n}$ for some constant $c$ depending on the channel.

Also, look at [rate distortion theory.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rate%E2%80%93distortion_theory)

This gives a formula for the highest rate at which you can transmit if you want to make sure that at most $\epsilon$ fraction of the transmitted bits are received erroneously.

Both of these quantify the cost of errors incurred when you transmit at $R>C$, and in most cases it's not worth it.